# RPM package naming convention

Tags: rpm

I'm a little confused with RPM package naming.

When I do:

```
vickey@tb:/usr/include$ rpm -qf event.h 
libevent-devel-2.0.10-2.fc15.i686
```

And:

```
vickey@tb:/usr/include$ repoquery --list  libevent-devel.i686
/usr/bin/event_rpcgen.py
/usr/include/evdns.h
/usr/include/event.h
....
....
```

Here in the second code box /usr/include/event.h is provided by libevent-devel.i686 but a query in the first code box shows that it belongs to the package libevent-devel-2.0.10-2.fc15.i686.

Does package manager use these aliases?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm simplifying things too much.

In your first example, you're are querying the local RPM database.  Usually, only one version of a RPM is installed.

A repo can contain many versions of the same package.  Therefore, it will display the RPM name and architecture only.

Comment: You might find the output of `repoquery -f /usr/include/event.h` interesting as well.